# mute/unmute toggle for background music? Change picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my background music:

```
<audio id="bgm" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="assets/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

I also tried making a mute button:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bgm').muted = true; return false">
    <img src="assets/vol.png"/>
</a>
```

As for unmuting it I am at a loss. Changing the picture? I am brand  new to web design so please forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I kind of want to -1 this just for having `autoplay` on..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just set it so that when you click the button it always does the opposite of what is currently set:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bgm').muted = !document.getElementById('bgm').muted; return false">
    <img src="assets/vol.png"/>
</a>
```